# How to keep document cursor visible even when losing focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to have a contentEditable div continue to show a non-blinking cursor even when it is not focused.  The exact behavior I am trying to emulate is how Google docs continues to show the document cursor even when you click on another part of the screen.  I am using React.

Answer (score 1):

Create refs for all the elements that you need and then set them to focus onBlur if they're still selected. If you look at the sandbox. I'm dynamically creating the editable divs and their refs. As for the non blinking cursor, you could create a custom one using css.

```
const handleBlur = () => {
  // Keep focus on selected element when blured
  elementsRef.current[selected].current.focus();
  };

useEffect(() => {
  // Set the current focused element
  elementsRef.current[selected].current.focus();
  }, [selected]);

 <div
      contentEditable
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      ref={elementsRef.current[index]}
      key={index}
      onClick={(e) => {
      setSelected(e.currentTarget.id);
       }}
      style={styles.input}
   ></div>
```

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-jasper-drlccv?file=/src/App.js